# Problem getting WebView to play Flash file

Tags: java, android, flash, webview

I have a WebView that is loading a URL that plays a Flash file. This works in the regular Android Browser, or if I use an Intent. For some reason it won't load in my WebView. It tells me I need to download Flash Player, even though it has already been installed:

```
public void setupWebView(){
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        if(webView != null){
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("http://66.135.33.137/apps/ibiybqepljofmg16xdvs/tv2beta/tvstation_viewer_v2.html");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON)` for your `WebSettings` object.

Comment: i added hardware acceleration to manafist but its not working [Nexus S] ?